# Neo4j - How to find shortest path between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have an extraordinarily basic question about Neo4j.

I've imported a simple dataset which contains a number of nodes as 'example_nodes' like so:

`sourceId`, `targetId`

Thus, my database has a simple two column table of sources and targets.

How could I find the shortest path between an arbitrary `sourceId` and `targetId`?

My initial attempt is along the lines of:

```
MATCH (source:example_nodes),(target:example_nodes),
p = shortestPath((source)--(target))
WHERE (source.sourceId) = 1234 AND (target.targetId) = 5678
return p
```

Which returns no records, when I can clearly see the first line in my database is itself a single path:

`{"sourceId":"1234","targetId":"5678"}`

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to create all the relationships before I can run a query (as all I've done so far is imported the nodes and created indices)

Comment: Yes, for a shortest path query, you need paths first, so don't attempt the query until you get relationships into the graph.

Answer (score 4):

You should find the `source` and `target` first, and then invoke `shortestpath`:

```
MATCH (source:example_nodes),(target:example_nodes)
WHERE source.sourceId = 1234 AND target.targetId = 5678
MATCH p = shortestPath((source)-[*]-(target))
return p;
```

If this query runs too long, try limiting the maximum path length searched. For example, use `[*..8]` to limit the length to 8.

Comment: Actually one thing I realized is that the target should be `target.sourceId` should it not? That said, modifying it so still returns no records, is it because I haven't created the relationships?

Comment: If you have no such relationships, then of course you wouldn't find any :-).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the target should be target.sourceId". The query in my answer is valid, as far as I understand your use case.

Comment: I think the question then is how to build these relationships :) Sorry, my brain is a bit foggy right now - I realize the statement about the target is incorrect.

Comment: You'd usually use [CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/#create-relationships) or [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#query-merge-relationships).

Comment: OK, I am now running `MATCH (start:example_nodes),(end:example_nodes)
WHERE start.targetId = end.sourceId
CREATE (start)-[r:RELTYPE]->(end)
RETURN r` let's see if this works :)

Comment: Hm, the command seemed to run for a long period of time, and never completed, there are 262867 nodes actually, so is this asking too much of neo4j?

Comment: That is a common issue with unlimited variable-length path patterns. See the last 2 sentences I added to my answer.

Comment: Ah, while your addition is definitely relevant, I had meant my attempt to create all the relationships seemed to fail

Answer (score 0):

A more compact and clean query would be:

```
match s=shortestPath((src {sourceId:1234})-[*]-(dst {targetId:5678})) return s
```